# Strong completeness of resolution in Boolean/propositional logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose we have a set of clauses $\Gamma$ that are disjunctions, so that the whole set can be viewed to represent a Boolean expression in CNF form. Then we can say $\Gamma$ entails the clause $C$ iff the set $\Gamma \cup \neg C$ is unsatisfiable. (Note that $\neg C$ is a set of unit clauses.)

For any such clause $C$, we can say that it is **trivially** entailed by $\Gamma$ if it meets one of the following conditions:

1. **Subsumption**: There is some clause $A \in \Gamma$ and some arbitrary disjunction $B$ such that $C = A \lor B$
2. **Tautology**: $C$ contains both a literal and its negation, and is true in every model

Otherwise, we say that $C$ is **nontrivially** entailed by $\Gamma$.

One procedure that can produce nontrivial clauses is [resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)), where we take two clauses sharing exactly one literal that differs in sign between them, and generate the clause that is the disjunction of all other literals in the two clauses. For example, $(a \lor b \lor c)$ and $(\neg c \lor d \lor e)$ resolve to $(a \lor b \lor d \lor e)$.

**My question:** Can repeated use of the resolution operator produce **every** non-trivially entailed clause from $\Gamma$?

In other words, do there exist non-trivially entailed clauses that we cannot obtain by repeated use of resolution on $\Gamma$ and intermediate resolvents?

Formally speaking, this is equivalent to asking if the resolution operation, coupled with operations for subsumption and tautology, leads to a [**strongly complete**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Strong_completeness) formal system. This is a much stronger criterion than "refutation completeness," which resolution is known to have.

Comment: While $a \vee b$ is entailed by $a$, it cannot be obtained from $a$ by resolution.  Do you want to impose any restrictions on which variables appear in the entailed clause?

Comment: That's one of the trivially entailed clauses I listed under subsumption. I'm only asking about nontrivially entailed clauses.

Comment: Sorry, I rushed my comment.  The answer is that by repeated resolution one obtains all prime implicates of the given CNF formula.  See, for instance, [Boolean Reasoning: The Logic of Boolean Equations](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780792391210) by F. M. Brown.  Hence, all clauses entailed by the formula are entailed by some clause generated by resolution.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Had not seen the crossover since they use different terminology.

Comment: Glad to be of help.  It is also not difficult to produce a resolution proof that $\Gamma \wedge \neg C$ is unsatisfiable that is guaranteed to contain a clause $D$ that either is $C$ itself, or subsumes it.  A proof-producing CDCL SAT solver would normally do just that.  $D$ would also be returned as interpolant for $\Gamma \rightarrow C$.

Comment: Does "interpolant" here mean the same thing as "implicant?" Also, if you want to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it so you get points...

Comment: I mean Craig interpolant, and specifically, I'm thinking of Pudlak's algorithm for computing it.  An interpolant for $A \rightarrow B$ is a formula $I$ in the variables common to $A$ and $B$ such that $A \rightarrow I$ and $I \rightarrow B$.  Pudlak showed how to compute an interpolant from a resolution proof that $A \wedge \neg B$ is unsatisfiable.  If $B$ is a clause, then $I$ is also a clause: either one of the original clauses, or a clause derived from them by resolution.

Comment: In general, there are one or more interpolants, and the claim I made is for a specific way of computing one, on top of a specific way of producing the resolution proof.  They are specific, but they are commonly used.

Comment: Ah, I see. Do we have any upper or lower bounds on what the length of such a resolution proof for an unsatisfiable circuit must be? And I see what you mean now, that an interpolant is basically an intermediate clause (and hence must be generated by a chain of resolutions or subsumptions).

Comment: The resolution proof may be exponential in the length of the unsatisfiable formula. (First shown by Haken in *The 
intractability of resolution*. Theoretical Computer Science 39 (1985) 297-308.)  As for the interpolant, in general it is a formula, not necessarily a clause.  (Not sure if I made it clear.)  For instance, in $A \rightarrow B$, even if $B$ is a clause, as long as $A$ and $B$ have exactly the same variables, $A$ itself is an interpolant.  If $B$ is not a clause, there may not exist an interpolant that is a clause.

Comment: Thanks @FabioSomenzi - I just made a new post to try to get intuition for why resolution proofs can be so long. I've read Tseitin's and Haken's work but still don't have a good grasp of why resolution is so weak. If you have any insight I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: Perhaps the 1987 JACM paper by Urquhart, *Hard Examples for Resolution*, addresses your question, at least in part?

Comment: Thanks - I've been reading this and looking into other deduction techniques, such as asymmetric tautology/reverse unit propagation (which seems to generalize resolution). Do you know of any good literature which gives lower bounds for this broader set of implication operators, or in general other ones than resolution? Or do we know some system for which establishing lower bounds is equivalent to setting NP = co-NP?